# How do I make Chord shifting easy in guitar?

Tags: chords, acoustic-guitar

I am newbie in Guitar playing.

Although, I can play Guitar leads really well and also perform spider exercises and legatos but I am not getting comfortable to shift chords in guitar.
Are there any exercise for chord shifting?